# A Question about an article by Birman, Series

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, riemannian-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry, riemann-surfaces, geodesics

Birman and Series in their article [GEODESICS WITH BOUNDED INTERSECTION NUMBER ON
SURFACES ARE SPARSELY DISTRIBUTED](http://www.math.columbia.edu/%7Ejb/bdd-int.no-sparce.pdf) proved that the set of points on a hyperbolic surface (possibly with boundary) belonging to complete geodesics with at most $k$ self intersections are nowhere dense and of Hausdorff dimension $1$.

In section two of this article, they introduce non-exceptional geodesics relative to a fundamental region $R$, which are the complete geodesics that don't pass through the vertices of the fundamental region $R$ or don't have self intersections on the vertices. They claim that we can take $3$ fundamental regions so that any simple complete geodesic is non-exceptional relative to at least one of them.

I was trying to justify this part for myself, and I wasn't successful. Could it be possible for someone to help me prove this part.

Comment: Now also posted to m.se, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4695697/a-question-about-an-article-by-birman-series

Comment: I imagine that the rough idea would be some sort of general position and cut and paste to construct new polygons which systematical remove non-exception geodesics. In thinking about it I seem to always run into the "naive" problem that before this paper we did not know that these sets were measure zero and nowhere dense! That makes me think a somewhat clever construction is necessary outside my naive thoughts.

Comment: Maybe to get around this you could look at $\epsilon \to 0$ neighborhoods of $R$ and see if C-S arguments just "go through" (with some additional but negligible error), I would have to dig into the specifics though.

Comment: Guessing "working around" the set of self intersections (points on surface that arise from self intersection) is easier as it is much smaller set than the set of self intersecting curves and maybe leads to cut and paste arguments working